# MVC 2.0 View that starts with a number

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-routing, naming-conventions

I'm using c#, visual studio 2010. I'm new to MVC
I was supplied with a simple HTML page that I converted to an aspx view. I then added the controller.
The view directory is Views/150/Index.aspx. The issue is that when I go to add the controller, the class name is not allowed to be a number.

```
namespace MyPages.Controllers
{
    public class _50Controller : Controller
    {

        public ViewResult Index()
        {
            return View("Index");
        }

    }
}
```

When I entered the have the controller a number, it automatically changed it from 150 to _50. So I changed it to 150Controller.cs and changed the class name to 150Controller : Controller.
Unfortunately, you can't have a number as a class name, and _50Controller as the class name tries to direct to Views/_50/Index.aspx.
I would simply change the name, however I was specifically asked to have it as a number. I know I can set up a redirect in ISS... but is there another way to do this? 
Thanks!

Comment: Why should it be a number? may be you just need to have the number as a part the of the URI which in such cases you can use Areas or custom routes like url: "150/{controller}/{action}/{id}"

Comment: I was asked to have the page as a specific link. Like www.blah.com/mypages/150.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C# members cannot start with a number. You could use routing in order to achieve that:

For example you could have the following controller:

```
public class ErrorController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View("500");
    }
}
```

which could be routed like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Error",
    url: "500",
    defaults: new { controller = "Error", action = "Index" }
);
```

Now when you navigate to `http://example.com/500` it will be the `Index` action of `ErrorController` that will get executed and which will render the `500.aspx` view.

Comment: Using your example, should the actual page be in Views/Error/Index.aspx ?

Comment: No, it should be in `~/Views/Error/500.aspx`. But if you `return View();` instead of `return View("500");` (as shown in my answer) you could then have `~/Views/Error/Index.aspx`.